# angularjs $http post not working with Chrome browser

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, http, post

I'm trying to post an object to my rest service using angularjs.
Unfortunately it **isn't working with Google's Chrome browser. Firefox and Internet Explorer work perfectly fine!**

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Heres my Frontend -call:

```
    $scope.saveAssignment = function (cap, aId, wId, hId) {

//all the parameters are strings
    var postData = {
        assignmentId: aId,
        status: "CLOSED",
        startDate: new Date(),
        endDate: new Date(),
        captionText: cap,
        workerId: wId,
        segment_Id: hId
    };

    var header ={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    };

    $http.post("https://localhost:8443/rest/v1/saveAssignment", postData, header)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("IN SAVE ASSIGNMENTS - SUCCESS");
            console.log(status);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("ERROR!");

//As a response I get data = '' and status = 0
        })
}
```

I have the same problem if I deploy it (independent of localhost or not).

On the server-side (JPA), I'm accepting the call with:

```
@Path("saveAssignment")
public class SaveAssignment{
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveAss(String assJson) {
    System.out.println("TEST");
......
......
}
```

But not even the print statement "TEST" gets executed...

**UPDATE**

It looks like it has to be a CORS issue...
Chrome is only sending an OPTION request instead of an POST...
Idea how to fix this?
I already tried

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

but without succes... :(

**UPDATE 2**

Unfortunately I still don't manage to get it working. So I did a workaround by consciously excluding users with a Chrome browser from doing this post on my page (i.e. seeing the entire page)... (I used it for Amazon's Mechanical Turk, so it's not that severe). But it's not a solution for the origin problem... :-(

To exclude users with Google's Chrome browser I added the following:

```
$scope.chrome;

$scope.setIsChrome = function(){
   var chromium = window.chrome;
   var vendorName = window.navigator.vendor;
    if(chromium !== null && vendorName === "Google Inc.") {
      $scope.chrome = true;
    } else {
        $scope.chrome = false;
    }
}
```

You have to check additionaly for the vendor name, since the Opera browser return true for "window.chrome" as well...

Comment: What network tab in chrome dev tools says?

Comment: not very much...
status: (canceled)
type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
-----------------------------------------
[..]
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin:https://localhost:8443/rest[...]
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Request Payloadview source
[...]

Comment: Can you try removing "https:" from the post? Just start with "//localhost:8443/rest...".

Comment: unfortunately, the page is depending on https, since it's embedded in Amazon Mechanical Turk as an iframe and MTurk is requesting the page to be https...

Comment: Did you get a solution/work around for this? Pulling my hair from long time

Answer (score 0):

Is your angular app served via same HTTPS server? If `localhost:8433` has self-signed or not matching certificate then that may be your problem as Chrome usually displays security exception page in such case.

Just open any URL starting with `https://localhost:8443/` as normal page an then confirm security exceptions. That should help.

Update:

If you use iframe then the embedded page may be restricted by sandbox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh563496.aspx

Comment: good point, but that's not the problem, the self-signed certificate works normally fine... and as I said when I deploy the application, the behavior is identical... :/

Comment: Is your angular app served via same HTTPS server as AJAX?